# How to copy a Python class instance if deepcopy() does not work?

Tags: python, class, deep-copy

I would like to make a copy of a class instance in python. I tried `copy.deepcopy` but I get the error message:

> RuntimeError: Only Variables created explicitly by the user (graph leaves) support the deepcopy protocol at the moment

So suppose I have something like:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b, **kwargs):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        for x, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, x, v)

c = C(4,5,'r'=2)
c.a = 11
del c.b
```

And now I want to make an identical deep copy of `c`, is there an easy way?

Comment: Yes. Definitely. Override the `__copy__` dunder. Or the `__deepcopy__` one, depending on what you need.

Comment: Yes, you can use `copy.deepcopy`. so just `c2 = copy.deepcopy(c)` then `vars(c2) == {'a': 11, 'r': 2}` and `vars(c) == {'a': 11, 'r': 2}` but the traceback your are reporting wouldn't be produced by the class definition you gave...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ note, that isn't needed in this case. The `copy` module will handle types that don't define `__copy__` or `__deepcopy__` I don't think this has to do with that linked duplicate, the error message seems to suggest that deep-copy was purposefully overriden to throw the runtime error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Huh... well... CV as "off-topic" then? I've already voted.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, in actual fact I am trying to make a copy of a meta-class of `torch.nn.Module`, but that is a bit complicated, so I am giving a simpler example here. Just stating that  in my case `deepcopy` doesnt work, so i want another solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have mostly figured it out. The only problem which I cannot overcome is knowing an acceptable set of initialization arguments (arguments for `__init__`) for all classes. So I have to make the following two assumtions:

1) I have a set of default arguments for class `C` which I call `argsC`.
2) All objects in `C` can be initialized with empty arguments.

In which case I can
**First**:
Initialize a new instance of the class `C` from it's instance which I want to copy `c`:

```
c_copy = c.__class__(**argsC)
```

**Second**:
Go through all the attributes of `c` and set the attributes `c_copy` to be a copy of the attributes of `c`

```
for att in c.__dict__:
    setattr(c_copy, att, object_copy(getattr(c,att)))
```

where `object_copy` is a recursive application of the function we are building.

**Last**:
Delete all attributes in `c_copy` but not in `c`:

```
for att in c_copy.__dict__:
    if not hasattr(c, att):
        delattr(c_copy, att)
```

Putting this all together we have:

```
import copy

def object_copy(instance, init_args=None):
    if init_args:
        new_obj = instance.__class__(**init_args)
    else:
        new_obj = instance.__class__()
    if hasattr(instance, '__dict__'):
        for k in instance.__dict__ :
            try:
                attr_copy = copy.deepcopy(getattr(instance, k))
            except Exception as e:
                attr_copy = object_copy(getattr(instance, k))
            setattr(new_obj, k, attr_copy)

        new_attrs = list(new_obj.__dict__.keys())
        for k in new_attrs:
            if not hasattr(instance, k):
                delattr(new_obj, k)
        return new_obj
    else:
        return instance
```

So putting it all together we have:

```
argsC = {'a':1, 'b':1}
c = C(4,5,r=[[1],2,3])
c.a = 11
del c.b
c_copy = object_copy(c, argsC)
c.__dict__
```

> {'a': 11, 'r': [[1], 2, 3]}

```
c_copy.__dict__
```

> {'a': 11, 'r': [[1], 2, 3]}

```
c.__dict__
```

> {'a': 11, 'r': [[1, 33], 2, 3]}

```
c_copy.__dict__
```

> {'a': 11, 'r': [[1], 2, 3]}

Which is the desired outcome. It uses `deepcopy` if it can, but for the cases where it would raise an exception, it can do without.

Answer (score 41):

Yes you can make a copy of class instance using deepcopy:

```
from copy import deepcopy

c = C(4,5,'r'=2)
d = deepcopy(c)
```

This creates the copy of class instance 'c' in 'd' .

Comment: I specifically mention that this doesn't work for me. Because in my case, `deepcopy` gives an error. I specifically don't want a solution using `deepcopy`.

Comment: I was directed here from google for searching "how to deepcopy an instance of a class" and this works for me. So, I have to upvote...

Comment: `deepcopy` uses `pickle`, which breaks on some objects: `TypeError: can't pickle pygame.Surface objects` -- which is specifically what I was searching for a workaround here. So this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @lode Only answers that answer the question are to be upvoted. This is a clear downvote since the answerer either did not read or did not understand the question. Upvoting this only because it was in the search results and helped you to deepcopy a class is no option, it should be downvoted instead.

Answer (score 15):

One way to do that is by implementing `__copy__` in the `C` Class like so:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2
        self.var3 = 3

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        for x, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, x, v)

    def __copy__(self):
        self.normalizeArgs()
        return C(self.a, self.b, kwargs=self.kwargs)

    # THIS IS AN ADDITIONAL GATE-KEEPING METHOD TO ENSURE 
    # THAT EVEN WHEN PROPERTIES ARE DELETED, CLONED OBJECTS
    # STILL GETS DEFAULT VALUES (NONE, IN THIS CASE)
    def normalizeArgs(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "a"):
            self.a      = None
        if not hasattr(self, "b"):
            self.b      = None
        if not hasattr(self, "kwargs"):
            self.kwargs = {}

cMain   = C(a=4, b=5, kwargs={'r':2})

del cMain.b
cClone  = cMain.__copy__()

cMain.a = 11

del  cClone.b
cClone2 = cClone.__copy__()

print(vars(cMain))
print(vars(cClone))
print(vars(cClone2))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work, I get the error `      9     def __copy__(self):
---> 10         keywordArgs =  vars(self)['kwargs']
     11         return C(self.a, self.b, kwargs=keywordArgs)
     12 

KeyError: 'kwargs'`

Comment: Not also that it should work even after I delete a variable. So after doing `del c.a` I should be able to do `c_prime = c.__copy__()`.

Comment: And it should also deep copy the arguments. So if `c.a == [1,2]` I should not have `c.a == c_prime.a`.

Comment: it runs. But it doesn't solve my problem because, among other problems mentionned above. If I add the following line at the end of script: `cClone = cMain.__copy__()`, (i.e. after the `del` line), then I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'b'`

Comment: It also doesn't work if I exchange your line `cMain   = C(a=4, b=5, kwargs={'r':2})` for the line `cMain   = C(4,5,'r'=2)` as I have in my question.

Comment: The last problem can be solved by having:
`     def __copy__(self): \n keywordArgs =  vars(self) \n return C(**keywordArgs)` instead.

Comment: Yet another problem with your solution is that if I have `cMain = C([], 1, r=3)` and then `cClone = cMain.__copy__()`, then `cMain.a.append(1)`, then I have `cClone.a == [1]` but it should be `[]`.

Comment: @patapouf_ai You can implement a `gatekeeper` Method to account for those Scenarios... The Snippet above was updated to illustrate that... Please, comment if it's still not working for your use-case...  Also refer to: https://eval.in/938243